# Favorite Tags not available on mobile site

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

I like to use the stackoverflow mobile site on my phone.  The one feature that I really miss from the desktop version is the ability to see my list of favorite tags.

On the desktop version it is available on the home page and on my profile page but it isn't available on either of those pages on the mobile site.

Is it possible to access my favorite tags from the mobile site?

If not, please could it be added?  It would be useful if it would be available in such a way that it could be book marked so that people could add a direct link to it to their phones.

Comment: +1 yes, THIS. Please. @NickCraver are you out there? :-)

Comment: Any chance this could get looked at?  I had to use the mobile site for the first time a few days ago and it was REALLY frustrating, as my favorite tag isn't one of the ones on the default tag viewing page...

Comment: Also missing from the mobile app. Disappointing.