# Include Rep total for the day on mobile

Tags: feature-request, reputation, mobile-web

On mobile SO, the rep screen shows a very long and impractical list of every single question that has changed the reputation of the user.  While on desktop SO, this screen shows a nice total number next to the date, and a little arrow on the side that allows you to reveal the extended details of where and how much the user's rep has changed.  So, my question is, can we migrate this to mobile?  I'd much rather have a total next to the date with the little detail arrows on the side, than have to scroll through a massive list to check if I've hit the 200 rep wall on a daily basis.

Comment: +1 I'd also like to have easy access to my list of favorite tags on the mobile version. I don't currently see a way to do that. There's a request for this, but aside from my up-vote, it's all tumble-weeds. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107720/favorite-tags-not-available-on-mobile-site

Comment: Related, but without the little arrows: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112324/show-daily-rep-totals-on-mobile-site